# Select Distinct from multiple tables linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I have tow tables, tblItem and tblInsertLines, in tblInsertLines I have the same ItemId but with differnt ProdDate and ExpireDate, I want to get a distinct list of all items but select the first row from tblInsertLines as the first row contains the oldest ProdDate. 
Any help will be appreciated. I use this code.

```
public static List<Item> getItemList()
    {
        using (var db = new AWarehouseDataClassesDataContext())
        {

            var list = (from i in db.tblItems
                        join e in db.tblInsertLines on i.ItemId equals e.ItemId 
                        orderby i.NameE
                        select new Item
                        {
                            code = i.Code,
                            itemId = i.ItemId,
                            lastUpdate = i.LastUpdate,
                            nameA = i.NameA,
                            nameE = i.NameE,
                            qty = i.Qty,
                            prodDate = e.ProdDate,
                            expireDate = e.ExpireDate,
                            updatedBy = i.UpdatedBy
                        }).Distinct();
            return list.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want get first row according to oldest ProdDate?

Comment: yes. Or according to the oldest inserted row(lineId). This will also give the oldest inserted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
    var list= (from i in db.tblItems
                join e in db.tblInsertLines on i.ItemId equals e.ItemId 
                where e.counter > 0
                orderby i.NameE
                group new { i, e } by e.ItemId into g
                select new Item
                {
                    code = g.First().i.Code,
                    itemId = g.Key,
                    lastUpdate = g.First().i.LastUpdate,
                    nameA = g.First().i.NameA,
                    nameE = g.First().i.NameE,
                    qty = g.First().i.Qty,
                    prodDate = g.Min(x=>x.e.ProdDate),
                    expireDate = g.First().e.ExpireDate,
                    updatedBy = g.First().i.UpdatedBy
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Make note I have to return List<Item>. Can't use list.ToList();

Comment: First() method return only  Item object not List<Item>

Comment: you can return Item instead List<Item>

Comment: Then it is only one item object, I need to return a list of Items in warehouse.

Comment: I don't understand you. Do you want get first row according to oldest ProdDate? or List sorted by ProdDate?

Comment: In the table Item there are Items, the items are in the table InsertLines with different ExpireDates, I want to get the list of Items distinct but get the oldest ExpireDate

Comment: I understand you just minute

Comment: thank you, you saved me. I have one condition that should be in the way, where e.counter > 0. I have to test it.